# Download In-App content by MKStorekit

Tags: in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am using the MKStorekit library for IAPurchases. I wanted to ask that how I can download video that I have hosted on the Apple servers after calling this method

```
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager]buyFeature:@"myInAppID" onComplete:^(NSString *purchasedFeature, NSData *purchasedReceipt, NSArray *availableDownloads) {}
```

Does the "purchasedReceipt" contains the data or I have to get it from "availableDownloads" or do I have to implement my own logic over here buy using SKDownload.

Any help appreciated.